# Create video.js DOM elements in external div (controlbar)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, video.js, volume

How can I create video.js DOM elements (for example the volumebar) in an external div box?

In the API there is a short description of how component's DOM elements are created:
https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/volume-bar.html
Defined in https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/src/js/control-bar/volume-control/volume-bar.js line number: 27

But I don't understand how I can use this to create my own DOM elements in div boxes that are independent from the main videos.

```
 constructor(player, options) {
    super(player, options);
    this.on('slideractive', this.updateLastVolume_);
    this.on(player, 'volumechange', this.updateARIAAttributes);
    player.ready(() => this.updateARIAAttributes());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `player.addChild` method because it creates generic player's component tree. Instead you have to initialize component on your own:

```js
const VolumeBar = videojs.getComponent('VolumeBar');
var box = document.getElementById('volume-box');
var player = videojs('content_video');
var volumeBar = new VolumeBar(player);
// player calls dispose on children, but this is not a child
player.on('dispose', volumeBar.dispose.bind(volumeBar))
box.appendChild(volumeBar.el());
```

```html
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.3.0/video.js"></script>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.3.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<video id="content_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360">
  <source src="//commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" ></source>
</video>

<div id="volume-box" class="video-js" style="height: auto; overflow: auto;margin-top: 20px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was searching for. Is this documented somewhere? Because basically I'm trying to recreate most of the elements of the player the way you just presented (Play/pause, Volume, Progress bar, time left, Fullscreen). How do I know which variables I have to define for each element? The end goal is to create a new div with control bars that can activate two players at the same time (I managed to do this with play/pause already). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @NGVK Videojs is not designed for such customizations so the only way is to read docs + source code for each component and find out workarounds for it..

Comment: You actually do not need to do any of this, I built a complete and customised player with material ui controls by simply using react hooks and a single playerRef => forwardRef to separate video component. Just videojs.removeChild('controlBar') etc